# How edit the header access control allow to call database Api in browser?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i want retrive data from mongodb database using express API

javascript

```
$scope.nmr=function(){
    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8081/Blogs")
    .then(function (response)
            {$scope.Blog = ((response.data).slice(0,8));
            });
            };
```

html

```
 <span style=" font-size:25px; ">معبد حتبسوت</span>
    <span style="margin-right:10%;" ng-repeat="x in Blog">
    <div star-rating rating-value="x.AvgRate" max="5"></div>
    </span>
```

server.js/Api

```
 app.get('/Blogs', function (req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
  } else {
    //We are connected.
    console.log('Connection established to', url);

    db.collection('Blog').find().toArray(function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err

    console.log(result);
    res.end( JSON.stringify(result));
     })
     }
     });
     })
```

this error appear in browser but the data returned in the console

```
        [database server][1]
```

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8081/Blogs. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors this should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do like this:

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
        if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
          res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
          res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
          res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
          res.send(200);
        }
        else {
          next();
        }
    };

    app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

[cors in express](http://justindavis.co/2015/08/31/CORS-in-Express/)